# Where can I find the stormfang steel sword in skyrim: dragonborn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Does anybody got an idea where you can find the stormfang steel sword in skyrim: dragonborn?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Reaver Lord at **Brodir Grove** is wielding it. Simply **kill the Reaver Lord** (or pickpocket him with the proper perk) in order to obtain the weapon.

Stormfang actually respawns with the enemy after a couple of days. This makes it possible for you to get several instances of it, or to get a new one if you lose it.

Comment: Best way to make money!